# Result of Gzip compression is too long C#

Tags: c#, compression, gzip

I test the GZip algorithm to compress a base64 code but the result of function is too long than original code, original length is 228412 characters and the result 241041, but the result of [txtwizard](http://www.txtwizard.net/compression) compression is :

[image]

**this is my code :**

```
static string Compress(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return "";

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            zip.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        ms.Position = 0;
        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();

        byte[] compressed = new byte[ms.Length];
        ms.Read(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);

        byte[] gzBuffer = new byte[compressed.Length + 4];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(compressed, 0, gzBuffer, 4, compressed.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gzBuffer, 0, 4);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(gzBuffer);
    }
```

Comment: Just as a heads up, you probably want to dispose those MemoryStreams

Comment: What is your source text?  If it's already compressed/encrypted it may not be worth re-compressing for the reasons you're seeing.

Comment: It would be surprising that the raw zipped data is larger than the original but converting to base64 usually means more bytes, even on compressed data.

Comment: @ParrishHusband I don't think the zipped data is larger than the original, it's probably the conversion to base 64 that's making the result large

Comment: I assume the website you tested decodes the base64 BEFORE compressing the stream, then encode the result back to base64.
You, apply the compression directly on the base64 encoded text. That's probably why the end results are quite unsimilars.

Comment: @kipy yes after compressing of base64 string, the decompressing result is correct